# Why is $1=\mathbb{P}_i(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\left\{X_n=i\right\})=1$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be an irreducible and recurrent Markov chain with state space $E$ and Transition Matrix $P$. Then it is $1=\mathbb{P}_i(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{X_n=i\right\})$ for all $i\in E$, where
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}_i(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{X_n=i\right\})=\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{X_n=i\right\}|X_0=i).
> > $$

Using the Definition of the limes superior and the continuity of measures it is
\begin{align}
1&=\mathbb{P}_i(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{X_n=i\right\})\\
&=\mathbb{P}_i(\bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\bigcup_{n\geq k}\left\{X_n=i\right\}}_{\downarrow\text{ in }k})\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbb{P}_i(\underbrace{\bigcup_{n\geq k}\left\{X_n=i\right\}}_{\downarrow\text{ in }k})\\
&\implies 1=\mathbb{P}_i(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\left\{X_n=i\right\})~\text{ for any }k\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{align}

To be honest, I do not understand the last implication. Could you please tell my why this implication follows?

Comment: You could sure check how your questions was displayed in the browser before posting it.

Comment: @barakmanos Sorry, I corrected it, now it is displayed in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of recurrent is that given any initial starting position $x_k$ the probability that $X$ will return to $x_k$ is $1$. This is exactly that the event $\{X_n=x_0\}$ will occur for some $n>k$.

Comment: Not exactly--the difference being any return vs some return after some given time.

Comment: To be honest, I still cannot see why from $1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}_i(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\left\{X_n=i\right\})=1$ and $\bigcup_{n\geq k}\left\{X_n=i\right\}$ decreases in $k$ it follows that $\mathbb{P}_i(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\left\{X_n=i\right\})=1$ for any $k\geq 1$.